# Getting check_box to work in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My objective is to use a check box on the sign-in form to allow the user to choose to stay signed in after browser close. I'm using this code in the sign-in form for the check box (views > sessions > new.html.erb):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.check_box :stay_signed_in %> Stay signed in?
</div>
```

:stay_signed_in is therefore 1 if checked, and 0 if not. I then (attempt to) set a session variable :staysignedin to either true or false depending on the value of :stay_signed_in (in the sessions controller):

```
def create
  session[:staysignedin] = (params[:session][:stay_signed_in] == "1") ? true : false
  ...
end
```

There is something wrong with this code. Even when the box is checked and :stay_signed_in is definitely 1, session[:staysignedin] is never set to true. Where am I going wrong?

Edit:
The rest of the sign-in form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :stay_signed_in %>
    Stay signed in on this computer?
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Edit: correction: it IS setting session[:staysignedin] to be true or false correctly, so the fault must be elsewhere. The problem is that with 'stay signed in' checked, when I close the browser and reopen it, the user is not still signed in. When I remove the 'stay signed in?' check box on the sign in form and all the relevant code, leaving only the permanent sign-in code, it works fine.

```
def sign_in(user)
  if session[:staysignedin]
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  else
    session[:userid] = user.id
  end
  self.current_user = user
end

def sign_out
  if session[:staysignedin]
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  else
    session[:userid] = nil
    session[:staysignedin] = nil
  end
  self.current_user = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the rest of your form code look like?

My guess is that :stay_signed_in is not storing to `params[:session][:stay_signed_in]`, but rather `params[:something_else][:stay_signed_in]` or just `params[:stay_signed_in]`

If you're running on local WEBrick you can see the parameters that are posted with each request, that will help you make sure you've got the right parameter key.

-EDIT-

Based on your last comment, I would recommend using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to handle your authentication logic. It is super-easy to implement, fully Rails 3 compatible, and includes built in code for handling sessions and remembering to stay logged in.

It's probably not worth your time to get stuck for this long on a simple sessions remembering issue when there's such a good plugin available that is lightweight, rock-solid, well-documented etc.

For an intro, see this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise).

Comment: I believe I have the parameters correct - from WEBrick:  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q702NkNyTh08PRkLTt9TF2grtmVYiNYdXIUj3G+pszs=", "session"=>{"email"=>"user1@testing.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "stay_signed_in"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, looks like you have that right. Well, what else are you doing with the session and the params hash in the controller? Is it possible that you're resetting it to some default state somewhere else in the code?

Comment: It seems the non-permanent sign-in/out code is somehow intefering with the permanent sign-in code.

Comment: See above comment -- I don't know what's causing your problem, but you probably should consider just using a plugin and moving on to the code that makes your app unique. :)

Comment: I think I'll take that advice!